# How to find out what functions to intercept with LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: linux, elf, ld-preload

I am trying to intercept all dynamically loaded functions that call syscall `openat` with a library `comm.so` using `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism.

Consider the following use of `/sbin/depmod` command:

```
#strace -f /sbin/depmod 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64
```

(...)

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

I want to intercept the function that calls this `openat` syscall.

How to find out what is that function?  `openat`, which may be an alias, and any other similar function, do not work - nothing gets intercepted.

I tried to use this command to find what dynamically loaded functions my command is using:

```
#readelf -p .dynstr /sbin/depmod
```

this prints out some `.so` libraries, so I used `readelf` on them recursively.  At the end of the recursion, I have the following list of functions that have `open` and `at` in them:

```
openat
openat64
open_by_handle_at
__openat64_2
```

None of these work - they don't intercept the call returning the file descriptor 3.

OK, so how to find out what other function do I need to intercept? Do I have to go through *all* of the functions shown by `readelf` command, and recursively so, one by one (there is a lot of them)?

Comment: **Why do you want to do this?** What is the actual scenario? Edit your question to motivate it more and give more context (it could be some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Not sure what you mean??  I just want to intercept user functions that call `openat` system call.  This is a good scenario that lots of people follow all the time, no?

Comment: Yes, but why do you care about *every* `openat`, including those done by `ld-linux.so` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ??? Not sure again what you mean???  Of course I care about every one, it would be silly to care about some and not others, no matter by whom called.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did check all `open` calls as well, nothing there.

Comment: I find weird that you care about what `ld-linux.so` is doing (since it is implementing `LD_PRELOAD`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OK, look, in the above example, after that `strace` line, there is more lines, that use the file descriptor 3 and `openat` calls to open some files like `vdso`.  Now, just the file name like this is useless.  I need to know the whole path. To know the path, I have to know, what directory the descriptor 3 refers to.  Am I making sense??

Comment: I have, I wrote lots of stuff in the chat

Comment: I still don't understand your motivation and why would you care about `openat` done in `ld-linux.so`. You really should improve your question. Have you understood what is that file descriptor 3? Also `depmod` is a low-level sysadmin command (probably used by other utilities also), so why do you care?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch well, I want to know all files that `depmod` is accessing, OK? But not by hand, of course, programmatically. I can see from `strace` what is happening.  I want to repeat this by `LD_PRELOAD`, _as_best_possible_.

Comment: That should go into the question. And you don't tell why you care about `depmod`? Why using `strace` is not enough? And what about `depmod` processes called by other things (`modprobe`, perhaps `systemd`...)? You really need to explain what you really want to do. Isn't `lsmod` enough for you?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I appreciate, but with all due respect to your knowledge Basile, which is much deeper than mine... I am not a beginner, - I do not have a choice what to use, I need to understand `depmod` because that is what Linux build uses in certain places, I can't change that.

Comment: Then use `strace`, or wrap your system `depmod` with something else. Perhaps just a shell script running `strace depmod` (or your own C program doing `ptrace`). I'm sorry, but your question smells a lot like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) that you still hide. `depmod` is a deep sysadmin utility (and I cannot list all the cases that use it)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I could parse the output of `strace`, or use `ptrace`, the reason I don't, is because they are slow, and I cannot have such a performance penalty. That's why I am using `LD_PRELOAD` and yes it may not work 100% of the time, that is OK, so long as I know, this is a case where it cannot be done.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `depmod` is used by the Linux kernel build, that is all, and, I need to understand some things about that build, without slowing it down with `ptrace`, that's all. I mean, it's all very reasonable.

Comment: Then ask a question about the Linux kernel build. Or patch your `depmod` command (by compiling it from its source code, and e.g. adding appropriate outputs there, maybe some additional call to `syslog`). Or can't you use the `-v` option to `depmod` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No....  that would require that I ask a 1000 of questions.  I want to learn how to fish, not to give me fish one by one.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OK I think I spent just about as much of your valuable time as I feel comfortable spending, without you being on my payroll. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `openat` *system call* (or any other one, see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for a list) could be called without using the `openat` function from the standard library; and it could be called from [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) (which *handles* `LD_PRELOAD`). On my Debian/Sid system it looks that the dynamic linker `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`  is using `openat` system call (try for example `strace /bin/true`) and of course it uses its own `open` or `openat` function (not the one in `libc.so`).

Any system call could (in principle) be called by direct machine code (e.g. some appropriate `SYSENTER` machine instruction), or thru some indirect [syscall(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) (and in both cases the `openat` C function won't be used). See perhaps the [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) for more and the [Linux x86 ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) spec.

If you want to intercept all of them (including those done by `ld-linux`, which is weird), you need to use [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) with `PTRACE_SYSCALL` in a way similar to [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). You'll be able to get the program counter and the call stack at that point.

If you care about following files and file descriptors, consider also [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities.

If you use `gdb` (which can be painfully used on programs *without* DWARF debug information) you could [use `catch syscall`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html) (the way to use `ptrace PTRACE_SYSCALL` in `gdb`) to find out (and probably "break at") every raw system call.

BTW, it could be possible that some [C standard libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) are implementing their `open` C function with `openat` system call (or using `openat` elsewhere). Check by studying the source code of your particular `libc.so` (probably GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), maybe [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)).

Comment: OK, then how do I find out, in this specific example, just how is this `openat` syscall made? `ptrace` or `strace` won't tell me who made it, just that it is made.

Comment: You could use other  `ptrace` calls to query the program counter, the stack pointer, etc

Comment: OK, I checked that `syscall` is not doing it, and I like I said, I checked all the `openat` variations.  Are you saying, that necessarily means, it _must_ have been done by a machine instruction?

Comment: By definition *every* system call is triggered by some machine instruction like `SYSENTER`, `INT`, etc

Comment: OK, but does it mean, it must have been done without a user function?

Comment: I have no idea. Have you tried to use `gdb` with `catch syscall` to understand *when* and *how* is your `openat` called?

Comment: `gdb` well, that would require that the command `depmod` must be compiled with `-g` ? But I don't have the sources to compile it myself.

Comment: `gdb` can painfully be used on executables without DWARF information (that is compiled without `-g`). And `depmod` (part of `kmod` package on my Debian system) is some free software that you could recompile with `-g`

Comment: @MarkGaleck Basile could setting up a debugging trace through ftrace via debugfs be a viable option?  It might mean digging through the SRC of your kernel version but you can have pattern matching (eg open*)

Comment: There's even a test under `perf` tools for [openat](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/tools/perf/tests/openat-syscall-all-cpus.c) profiling